# Adding Animation to Object—Unexpected Behavior

Tags: unity

I've been following the [Unity 2D roguelike tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike) and I'm a bit confused about something. When he drags a series of sprites to his player object, a dialog box appears that prompts him to name and choose a location for his animation. I have seen this behavior in a couple video tutorials now.

When I do this, it simply creates the animation and animation controller in the sprite folder and nothing more. This becomes a bit tedious after a while and I'm not sure these animations are being associated with the object correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Create a Animation folder and put them in it for Organization purposes. The animations you create will be associated with the animated controller you use while creating them.
After you point it to the Animation Folder the next time you go to create one the directory should be showing the same as in the tutorial. When dragging multiple sprites at once it will automatically create the controller and name it the first sprite of the bunch then will prompt you to name the animation.